# ALM, VSTS 2010 : is it possible to create custom checkin policy in local machines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, checkin, alm

I am trying to enfore a custom checkin policy to my dev team.

the customr policy is aimed @ alerting the dev with a list of checkpoints before the checkins happen.

I am not the administrator of TFS 2010.

Is it possible to install custom policies for each developer machine?

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible, BUT you need the help of your TFS administrator **once**. He needs to activate the custom policy on your TFS project centrally, otherwise your check-in actions do not trigger the custom policy to be activated.

1. Create you custom policy.
2. Upload it to your projects version control tree according to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2011/03/27/distributing-custom-check-in-policies-amp-wit-controls-using-team-members.aspx
3. Distribute TFS Powertools in your team to distribute and sync your custom policies.
4. Ask the TFS administrator to activate your custom policy.

Is this an acceptable scenario for your situation?